# Login crash and can't open terminal 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, command-line, login, crash

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The login is now frozen : i.e. I enter my password correctly and a few seconds after the login page appears again. The other problem is I can't open any terminal when I am on the login page.

This problem occurred after I tried to force to install a program doing:

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Do you have any idea how I can solve my problem 
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

On the Login page press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and use your login credentials to log into the TTY.

Then do:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -r <packagename>
sudo apt-get -f install
# now check if all runs smootly
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

If this will not work you have to access the machine via the rescue options root. To do this press <kbd>shift</kbd> when the BIOS is done doing it's work (you ma need a couple of tries to get the timing right), there you can then choose `Advanced options for Ubuntu --> <newest kernel> (recovery)` there you will then be greeted by a dos like selcetion menu where you can choose to be `root`. there you want then to do the above procedure after having remounted your HDD to be read/write access.

```
# replace sdX with the actual drive name
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdX
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is I got a black screen when do ctrl +alt+f1 , I can't open a terminal from the login page. Do you have any other idea.

Comment: @Clairera indeed I'm not out of ideas yet, i have updated my answer :) have a look.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I manage to have access to the terminal, using the recovery mode. I did the updating and upgrading but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Do you want to come into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39565/videonauths-help-box) maybe we can figure this out.

Comment: Unfortunatly I must have 20 reputations on the SEN to talk there.

Comment: Reboot the computer and go into `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` --> ` Ubuntu (recovery mode)` and access the recovery shell. You should be able to login with your own password, then remount filesystem read write with `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` , and remove whatever package you installed.